# Is it safe to modify a file with a hex editor in this manner?

Tags: hex-editors

There's a file I'd like to modify with a hex editor (add some new code/functionality), but I'm not sure if I'll find enough blank space in the program for the new material.  So I've got a couple of questions about what is safe to do:

1. The file has a large sequence of 00s near the end, which will almost certainly be enough.  Is it safe to write this, or do I have to worry that that area is reserved for the program to write to in the course of its normal operation?
2. If I have to add on to the file size, is there a danger of corrupting other files by overwriting them (I'm using HxD, if that matters)?  I've got the space for a larger file, I just don't want to corrupt other files.
3. If I do change the file size, is there anything else that needs to be changed to match?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add bytes to the end of a program and expect it will know what to do with them.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought of that.  Obviously I would need to use a jump command at the appropriate place to have it run the relevant code; the question is whether I risk overwriting anything important or it will make the program not work.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not answer that.  Experimentation seems like a good road to travel.  Also an examination of the PE file format (msdn or others)